# handlebarsjs acces context by numerical id

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have a json context like this:

```
{
 "jobsCountPerFilter": {
  "10": {
   "1170835": 17,
   "1170836": 3,
   "1170867": 1,
   "1170868": 5,
   "1170869": 4,
   "1172193": 5,
   "1172195": 5
  }
 }
}
```

in handlebars i try to access the data like this:

```
{{#each filter_10.values as | value key |}}
 direct: {{jobsCountPerFilter.[10].[1170835]}} <-- THIS WORKS
 key: {{key}}, value: [{{jobsCountPerFilter.[10].[key]}}]     <-- THIS DOESN'T, NO ERROR, NO OUTPUT
{{/each}}
```

output in the html:

```
direct: 17
key: 1170835, value: []
```

key == 1170835

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

It has to do something with the type, because:

```
(compare key "1170835") returns TRUE
(compare key 1170835)   returns FALSE
```

so i guess key is a string but in the context it's a number, how do i solve this?

EDIT:

```
"filter_10": {
    "values": {
      "1170835": "A",
      "1170836": "B",
      "1170867": "C",
      "1170868": "D",
      "1170869": "E"
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you say `THIS DOESN'T WORK` what error or indication is there of that?  Can you confirm the value of `key`?

Comment: sorry..it doesn't spit an error, it just doesn't return anything, as it wouldn't find anything with that key (the value of key is in that scope 1170835

Comment: What is `filter_10.values`?

Comment: I am not sure why Handlebars doesn't understand a String used within square brackets as you are doing with your String `key`s in `jobsCountPerFilter.[10].[key]`, but I would suggest using the [`lookup helper`](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup), as in `{{lookup jobsCountPerFilter.[10] key}}`.

Comment: how did i miss the lookup!? that looks promising, I have one more little issue with it...if a key isn't found (which can happen) the whole array is returned, how can i avoid that?

Comment: looks like the easiest is to have a custom helper, too bad the square brackets behave like that